# @PreUpdate com @Transient - EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-link

Preciso que um método @PreUpdate seja chamado quando um atributo @Transient for modificado. Esse @Transient sempre será modificado, então, sim, o @PreUpdate teria que ser chamado sempre.
Já que ele terá que ser chamado sempre, procurei uma opção semelhante ao @PreUpdate, mas que fosse chamada independentemente de ter atributos modificados ou não, pois é esse método que irá definir o valor de uma coluna a ser persistida, de acordo com o valor no @Transient.
A alternativa que encontrei foi definir os seguintes atributos:

```
@Column(name="valor")
private Double valor;

@Column(name="valor", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Double valorTransientDisfarcado;
```

Desse forma, o *"transient"* sempre será carregado com o valor da coluna que  ele irá, possivelmente, alterar.
Caso esse *"transient"* seja alterado , ele irá cair no @PreUpdate e realizar algumas operações que irão definir se o valor que ele possui será   transmitido para o atributo *"original"* a ser persistido.

> A pergunta é: Quais os problemas que essa abordagem pode trazer?

E existe alguma alternativa para esse valor *"transient"*?
Melhor ainda, existe alguma alternativa para o @PreUpdate, para que o método seja chamado no último momento possível, independente se houver alterações, até o momento, a serem persistidas, para que ele só realize a verificação dos atributos modificados após esse método?

Comment: Como esse atributo seria @Transient você não poderia colocar essa lógica de @PreUpdate no setter desse atributo?
Assim, quando o valor do transient for alterado (através do `setTransient()`) ele pode ser validado e modificar o outro atributo `valorTransientDisfarcado`

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo bons princípios de separation of concerns (SoC) não seria legal delegar essa regra para sua camada de persitência de dados. Perceba que olhando apenas seu trecho de código já existe uma redundância no nome da coluna, que dificulta a legibildiade.

Prefira usar as ferramentas de Orientação à objetos (OO) já que esse campo não é persistido e usar, por exemplo, um [decorator](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator) na sua classe com os devidos getters/setters.

Vide o [Zen do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), preceitos de boas práticas de programação, que

> explícito é melhor que implícito.

Por tanto eu recomendo fortemente que você coloque suas regras em uma DAO e escreve casos de teste automatizado. É um caminho bem menos tortuoso que observar o ciclo de vida das entidades.